# How do you mock directives to enable unit testing of higher level directive?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In our app we have several layers of nested directives. I'm trying to write some unit tests for the top level directives. I've mocked in stuff that the directive itself needs, but now I'm running into errors from the lower level directives. In my unit tests for the top level directive, I don't want to have to worry about what is going on in the lower level directives. I just want to mock the lower level directive and basically have it do nothing so I can be testing the top level directive in isolation.

I tried overwriting the directive definition by doing something like this:

```
angular.module("myModule").directive("myLowerLevelDirective", function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
});
```

However, this does not overwrite it, it just runs this in addition to the real directive. How can I stop these lower level directives from doing anything in my unit test for the top level directive?

Comment: Your nested directives depend on, or use things out of, the outer directive?

Comment: The outer directive essentially passes information into the inner directive.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Due to the implementation of the directive registration, it does not seem possible to replace an existing directive by a mocked one.

However, you have several ways to unit test your higher level directive without interference from lower level directives :

1) Do not use lower level directive in your **unit test template** :

If your lower level directive is not added by your higher level directive, in your unit test use a template with only you higer-level-directive :

```
var html = "<div my-higher-level-directive></div>";
$compile(html)(scope);
```

So, lower level directive will not interfere.

2) **Use a service** in your directive implementation :

You can provide the lower level directive linking function by a service :

```
angular.module("myModule").directive("myLowerLevelDirective", function(myService) {
    return {
        link: myService.lowerLevelDirectiveLinkingFunction
    }
});
```

Then, you can mock this service in your unit test to avoid interference with your higher level directive. This service can even provide the whole directive object if needed.

3) You can overwrite your lower level directive with a **terminal directive** :

```
angular.module("myModule").directive("myLowerLevelDirective", function(myService) {
    return {
        priority: 100000,
        terminal: true,
        link: function() {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
});
```

With the terminal option and a higher priority, your real lower level directive will not be executed. More infos in the [directive doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#directivedefinitionobject).

See how it works in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uYtGQxJFKehR1NX60ssr?p=preview).

Comment: For #1, the lower level directive is in the template string of the higher level directive. I'm not including it in my test, but it gets brought in through the compilation process. For #2, it is an interesting an idea that seems like it would work, but I'm not sure if I like the idea of my directive definition off in some service somewhere.

Comment: I have just added a #3

Comment: #3 appears to do the same thing as what I did in my original question. It runs both directives.

Comment: I have unit test it in a plunker, I add the link at the end of my answer.

Comment: I don't have time right now to see what the plunker is doing, but I appreciate your efforts, and this answer certainly gives me some options. As the bounty is expiring, I want to award that before it does expire.

Comment: Thanks, don't hesitate if you have questions about the plunker

Comment: I looked at the plunker and do indeed both run. With what you did, I can ensure that the one in the test runs last, but I don't want the other one running at all. See http://plnkr.co/edit/S1BgF97kRrAKAQs5Y9vk?p=preview

Comment: In the plunker, there is two tests : one without the terminal directive and one with it. If you deactivate the without terminal directive test, the real lower directive never runs. See http://plnkr.co/edit/5RJeV8T7u2uT3ETWJjXJ?p=preview

Comment: Having had some time to look at this closer, I see what's going on now. This does effectively stop the lower directive from running, but the problem is that it prevents ALL directives from running. The specific directive I'm trying to test has an `ng-switch` in it, and I'm running into problems with stuff being run that should have been `ng-switch`ed out. See http://plnkr.co/edit/yKMWVxbcV0s7m3ufAcbo?p=preview

Comment: Right after posting that previous comment, I realized what the solution is. All my directives currently don't have a priority set (meaning it is 0), so the directive in the test just needs a priority higher than that in order to stop the real directive from running. I can just set the priority to 1, and thus the higher priority angular directives can still run. See http://plnkr.co/edit/bmoxPDpKtzJhc73yq1nP?p=preview Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you have to tweak your code just to make your tests work, then there is something wrong with the tests.

Answer (score 82):

Directives are just factories, so the best way to do this is to mock the factory of the directive in using the `module` function, typically in the `beforeEach` block. Assuming you have a directive named do-something used by a directive called do-something-else you'd mock it as such:

```
beforeEach(module('yourapp/test', function($provide){
  $provide.factory('doSomethingDirective', function(){ return {}; });
}));

// Or using the shorthand sytax
beforeEach(module('yourapp/test', { doSomethingDirective: {} ));
```

Then the directive will be overridden when the template is compiled in your test

```
inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
  $compile('<do-something-else></do-something-else>', $rootScope.$new());
});
```

Note that you need to add the 'Directive' suffix to the name because the compiler does this internally: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/821ed310a75719765448e8b15e3a56f0389107a5/src/ng/compile.js#L530

Comment: This works better than @Sylvain's solution for me b/c it overrides any dependencies that the directive may have -- otherwise you have to mock those out too.

Comment: @ElliotWinkler IMO, having to mock the dependencies *is* a good thing. It forces you to tests the directive as a unit.

Comment: I realize this, but my point is that I shouldn't have to mock secondary dependencies of the thing I'm testing, only primary dependencies. In other words, I shouldn't have to care what the directive depends upon in my test.

Comment: If someone have this problem when using coffescript:
[ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object
-> return null on the end of beforeEach  : https://gist.github.com/jbrowning/9527280

Comment: If you want to mock with custom behavior, you should return an array of directive definition objects: https://gist.github.com/pswai/ee51b0567f51c39d81c2

Comment: @PSWai that's right, and you also need to use the compile function pattern in the Directive Definition Object (if you only have a link, it won't get called).

Comment: @PSWai also, if you want to use scope bindings or bindToController, you need to manually do everything that `$compileProvider.directive()` does behind the scenes: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.5/src/ng/compile.js#L837-L865

Answer (score 66):

The clean way of mocking a directive is with `$compileProvider`

```
beforeEach(module('plunker', function($compileProvider){
  $compileProvider.directive('d1', function(){ 
    var def = {
      priority: 100,
      terminal: true,
      restrict:'EAC',
      template:'<div class="mock">this is a mock</div>',
    };
    return def;
  });
}));
```

You have to make sure the mock gets a higher priority then the directive you are mocking and that the mock is terminal so that the original directive will not be compiled.

```
priority: 100,
terminal: true,
```

The result would look like the following:

Given this directive:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.directive('d1', function(){
  var def =  {
    restrict: 'E',
    template:'<div class="d1"> d1 </div>'
  }
  return def;
});
```

You can mock it like this:

```
describe('testing with a mock', function() {
var $scope = null;
var el = null;

beforeEach(module('plunker', function($compileProvider){
  $compileProvider.directive('d1', function(){ 
    var def = {
      priority: 9999,
      terminal: true,
      restrict:'EAC',
      template:'<div class="mock">this is a mock</div>',
    };
    return def;
  });
}));

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  el = $compile('<div><d1></div>')($scope);
}));

it('should contain mocked element', function() {
  expect(el.find('.mock').length).toBe(1);
});
});
```

A few more things:

- When you create your mock, you have to consider whether or not you need `replace:true` and/or a `template`. For instance if you mock `ng-src` to prevent calls to the backend, then you don't want `replace:true` and you don't want to specify a `template`. But if you mock something visual, you might want to.
- If you set priority above 100, your mocks's attributes will not be interpolated. See [$compile source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js?source=c#L1844). For instance if you mock `ng-src` and set `priority:101`, then you'll end-up with `ng-src="{{variable}}"` not `ng-src="interpolated-value"` on your mock.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D2gRHPTkjklh2IZtny3Y?p=preview) with everything. Thanks to @trodrigues for pointing me in the right direction.

[Here is some doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) that explains more, check the "Configuration Blocks" section. Thanks to @ebelanger!

Comment: how would one restore the mock after testing so that future usage of the directive will employ the original factory?

Comment: providing within a module() applies the mock only to current unit test, so whatever changes you make to the directive, they will not be visible to other tests (unless you use window object, but you probably shouldn't)

Comment: `$compileProvider` works great. If you're using coffeescript and getting error `'fn' is not a function, got $CompileProvider`, make sure to return `undefined` from the `module` function.

Comment: One small comment though: If the directive you're mocking is doing transclusion, the high priority will prevent ng-transclude from working. In this case, my solution is to simply transclude manually inside the link function: `link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrls, transFn) { transFn(scope, function(clone) { element.append(clone); }); }`

Comment: Sir, please go up! This solution works for me, `$provide.factory` didn't work at all.

Answer (score 5):

You can modify your templates inside `$templateCache` to remove any lower level directives:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('path/to/template.html', '<div></div>');
}));
```

Answer (score 4):

Loved [Sylvain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21923462/635069) so much I had to turn it into a helper function. Most often, what I need is to kill off a child directive so that I can compile and test the parent container directive without its dependencies. So, this helper lets us do that:

```
function killDirective(directiveName) {
  angular.mock.module(function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.directive(directiveName, function() {
      return {
        priority: 9999999,
        terminal: true
      }
    });
  });
}
```

With that, you can completely disable a directive by running this *before* the injector gets created:

```
killDirective('myLowerLevelDirective');
```

Answer (score 2):

Being forced to think about this more myself, I have come up with a solution that fills our needs. All of our directives are attributes, so I created an `attributeRemover` directive for use during the unit tests. It looks something like this:

```
angular.module("myModule").directive("attributeRemover", function() {
    return {
        priority: -1, //make sure this runs last
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            var attributesToRemove = attrs.attributeRemover.split(",");
            angular.forEach(attributesToRemove, function(currAttributeToRemove) {
                element.find("div[" + currAttributeToRemove + "]").removeAttr(currAttributeToRemove);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Then the html for the directive I'm testing looks something like this:

```
<div my-higher-level-directive attribute-remover="my-lower-level-directive,another-loweler-level-directive"></div>
```

So, when `my-higher-level-directive` gets compiled the `attribute-remover` will have already removed the attributes for the lower level directives and thus I don't have to worry about what they are doing.

There's probably a more robust way of doing this for all kinds of directives (not just attribute ones) and I'm not sure if this works if only  using the built-in JQLite, but it works for what we need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another small idea. Just put this code in jasmine helpers (coffee script)

```
window.mockDirective = (name, factoryFunction) ->
  mockModule = angular.module('mocks.directives', ['ng'])
  mockModule.directive(name, factoryFunction)

  module ($provide) ->
    factoryObject = angular.injector([mockModule.name]).get("#{name}Directive")
    $provide.factory "#{name}Directive", -> factoryObject
    null
```

And use it:

```
beforeEach mockDirective, "myLowerLevelDirective", ->
  link: (scope, element) ->
```

This will completely remove all other implementations of given directive, giving a full access to test passed arguments to the directive. FOr example, mm.foundation alert directive can be mocked with:

```
beforeEach mockDirective 'alert', ->
  scope:
    type: '='
```

and then tested:

```
expect(element.find('alert').data('$isolateScopeNoTemplate').type).toEqual
```