# jasmine + karma - Firefox does not calculate element.height and element.width properly

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a strange problem using jasmine and karma frameworks.
Basically I just want to make a resize using plain javascript of some img's.

I have the following test :

```
    it('Should set both the height and width style for the one applicable as being the maximum allowed', function () {
    var images = '<img class="resizableImage" src="" alt="" style="height: 1200px; width: 1000px; visibility: hidden;">' +
        '<img class="resizableImage" src="" alt="" style="height: 1100px; width: 199px; visibility: visible;">' +
        '<img class="resizableImage" src="" alt="" style="height: 1990px; width: 200px; visibility: visible;">';
    setFixtures(images);

    var allResizableImages = $('img.resizableImage');
    resizeImagesWidthHeightIfBiggerThan(allResizableImages, 199, 199);

    $.each(allResizableImages, function () {
        expect($(this).css('width')).toBe('199px');
        expect($(this).css('height')).toBe('199px');
    });
});
```

and the function :

```
function resizeImagesWidthHeightIfBiggerThan(imagesToBeResized, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
var UNIT = "px";
var VISIBILITY_SETTINGS = "visible";

for (var i = 0, len = imagesToBeResized.length; i < len; i++) {
    var imgCandidate = imagesToBeResized[i];

    if (imgCandidate && imgCandidate.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
        if (imgCandidate.width > maxWidth) {
            imgCandidate.style.width = maxWidth + UNIT;
        }
        if (imgCandidate.height > maxHeight) {
            imgCandidate.style.height = maxHeight + UNIT;
        }
    }

    imgCandidate.style.visibility = VISIBILITY_SETTINGS;
}
```

}

With **Chrome**, everythings goes well.
However, with **Firefox**, the test *doesn't* pass.
Though, live (doing testing manually on Firefox), everything goes well.

What could be wrong ?

I am using **Firefox 29.0**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What happens if you remove the UNIT constant and use jquery in tests as well?

Comment: If I use jquery works. But the whole point is not to use jquery as I have some performance issues using it.

Comment: The thing is that testing live works but testing through karma doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log` the values in FF to see if the strings are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same problem. FF does not report correct image sizes if `src` is empty. Try and set `src` to a valid image to see if it works.

In our project we use `ng-src`; not `src`. We created a mock of `ng-src` that kicks-in in all our tests. The mock replaces the `ng-src` value (empty or not) with a single fake image stored in `/tests/image`. This is useful if you unit test directives that include images in their html template. See also [How do you mock directives to enable unit testing of higher level directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533052/how-do-you-mock-directives-to-enable-unit-testing-of-higher-level-directive/21923462#21923462)

Comment: If this solves your issue, you could change the title of your question to someting related to image sizes on FF. This will help other people find the solution.

Comment: By the way, antoher problem we faced is that IE8 does not calculate image sizes correctly if you are using `width` and `height` CSS properties. We had to to set `min-width` and `min-height` as a workaround.