# mock an AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, mocking

I have the following directive:

```
function InfoListDirective($rootScope, $restApi) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: staticFilesUri + 'templates/InfoList.Template.html',
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            refreshItemList: '&',
            canAddNew: '@',
            name: '@',
            linkTo: '@',
            deleteItem: '&',
            canDelete: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.kobocatLinkExists = function (item) {
                return window.koboConfigs && window.koboConfigs.kobocatServer;
            };


            scope.getHashLink = function (item) {
                var linkTo = scope.linkTo;
                return linkTo ? '/' + linkTo + '/' + item.id : '';
            };

            scope.getLink = function (item, format) {
                if(!format) {
                    format = "xml";
                }
                return scope.name.toLowerCase() + '/' + item.id + "?format=" + format;
            };

            scope.canDelete = scope.canDelete === 'true';
            $rootScope.canAddNew = scope.canAddNew === 'true';

            $rootScope.activeTab = scope.name;
        }
    };
}
```

It uses this template:

```
<header class="forms-header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="forms-header__title">Form Drafts</h1>
    <a href="#/builder" class="forms-header__button">+ Add Form</a>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="forms-filter">
    <div class="forms-filter__search">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i> <input class="forms-filter__searchbox" placeholder="Search forms"  ng-model="searchCriteria" />
    </div>
    <select class="forms-filter__sorter">
      <option>Sort</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="info-list">
      <div class="forms__card" ng-repeat="item in items|orderBy:'-date_modified'">
        <div kobocat-form-publisher class="forms__card__kobocat" item="item" ng-show="kobocatLinkExists()">

        </div>
        <div class="forms__card__info">
          <a class="forms__card__title" href="#{{ getHashLink(item) }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
          <p class="forms__card__description">{{ item.description || '' }}</p>
          <p class="forms__card__date">
            {{item.date_modified.getMonth()+1}}/{{item.date_modified.getDate()}}/{{item.date_modified.getYear() + 1900}}
          </p>
          <p class="forms__card__question-count">
            {{ item.rowCount }}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="forms__card__buttons">
          <a class="forms__card__buttons__button blue" href="{{ getLink(item, 'xml') }}"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></a>
          <a class="forms__card__buttons__button gray" href="{{ getLink(item, 'xls') }}"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
          <a class="forms__card__buttons__button red" href="" ng-click="deleteItem({item: item})"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

notice on line 19 there's another angular directive.

Everything works fine in the app but my unit tests for `InfoList` Directive started failing when I added this `kobocat-form-publisher` directive to the template. How can I mock this directive for the purpose of getting the `InfoList` directive tests passing again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried mocking a directive before, but I would think this works

(assuming Jasmine)

```
beforeEach(module('yourModuleName', function($provide) {
    var yourMock = $provide.value('yourMockDirective');
    $provide.value('kobocatFormPublisherDirective', yourMock);
});
```

Given that it works, you'll still have to have a mock implementation which you probably don't want to have sitting in production code which you would need to have loaded into the module. That's the part I'm not 100% sure will work, you might have to declare the directive inline.

On a sidenote, if it's a unit test I assume you're compiling the directive inside the test, in which case a more pragmatic solution is to just remove the external directive from the HTML before compiling it.

Comment: Yes, that might work. Since it's a directive inside a directive I'm not declaring the directive I want to mock out inside my test, but I could transform the directive's template before compiling it. I'll give it a try, tell you how it went. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that worked. I ended up doing `$templateCache.put('templates/InfoList.Template.html', $templateCache.get('templates/InfoList.Template.html').replace('kobocat-form-publisher', ''))` in my beforeEach method. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I still think the `$provide` approach would also work, but the replace is a lot less work :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21923462/302793) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17533052/302793) ("How do you mock directives..."), the 'correct' way is to use the `$compileProvider` service. The solution in short: It allows you to declare a directive with the same name but higher priority than your original directive. Setting terminal: true prevents your original directive from being compiled.