# Mocking Angular bootstrap-ui directive for unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a unit test to ensure that a directive works correctly.

The directive's template includes the [Angular bootstrap datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), so I would like to be able to mock that.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533052/how-do-you-mock-directives-to-enable-unit-testing-of-higher-level-directive) says I should be able to mock directives by creating new directives with the same name using `$compileProvider` and setting a high `priority` and `terminal` to true:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  inject([
    '$compileProvider',
    function($compileProvider) {
      $compileProvider.directive('datePickerOptions', {
        priority: 100,
        terminal: true,
        template: ''
      });

    $compileProvider.directive('datePickerPopup', {
      priority: 100,
     template: ''
    });
  }]);
});
```

It also says that you can mock directives by just overriding their factory functions like so:

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  $provide.factory('datePickerOptionsDirective', function() {
      return {};
  });
  $provide.factory('datePickerPopupDirective', function() {
      return {};
  });
}));
```

Neither of these methods are working for me. I'm using Karma unit tests. Any thoughts?

Comment: I recently learnt about the second method that you described, and took the opportunity to test it out. I was able to replace the directive factory using the $provide service. Are you getting any errors? What are trying to test? How are you doing it? Any chance, you can put up a plunk or fiddle of the test?

Comment: @Scorpion-Prince You're right, using `$provide` does work. My mistake was that Angular UI Bootstrap defines the directive as `datepicker` and not `datePicker` like I was putting. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This was my error. The [Datepicker code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js) lists its directives as `datepicker`, `datepickerPopup`, and `datepickerOptions`. The error was a capitalization issue.