# Why does $compileProvider have a directive method?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I observe from the Angular documentation, that `$compileProvider` has both a `directive()` and `component()` method. See:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider

I also observe the usage of that directive in the docs
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Search for: 'compileExample'

But I don't see any explanation of the purpose.

**Questions**

Q) Why does $compileProvider have a directive method? What's the purpose or benefit?

Q) How is registering a directive with the compiler different from declaring a directive on a module?

Answer (score 1):

> How is registering a directive with the compiler different from declaring a directive on a module?

The [module loader](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module) uses the `$compileProvider.directive()` method to load directives:

> [AngularJS Module Loader Source Code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/loader.js#L272)
>
> ```
> /**
>    * @ngdoc method
>    * @name angular.Module#directive
>    * @module ng
>    * @param {string|Object} name Directive name, or an object map of directives where the
>    *    keys are the names and the values are the factories.
>    * @param {Function} directiveFactory Factory function for creating new instance of
>    * directives.
>    * @description
>    * See {@link ng.$compileProvider#directive $compileProvider.directive()}.
>    */
>   directive: invokeLaterAndSetModuleName('$compileProvider', 'directive'),
> ```

The difference is that the module loader is capable of decorating directives and does it before the config phase. I have not found a use case for adding directives during the config phase.

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS guide, on https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module, states:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
  value('a', 123).
  factory('a', function() { return 123; }).
  directive('directiveName', ...).
  filter('filterName', ...);

// is same as

angular.module('myModule', []).
  config(function($provide, $compileProvider, $filterProvider) {
    $provide.value('a', 123);
    $provide.factory('a', function() { return 123; });
    $compileProvider.directive('directiveName', ...);
    $filterProvider.register('filterName', ...);
  });
```

So we know at least the `$compileProvider`is to directives what `$provider`is to factories.

There is at least one important use case for `$compileProvider`: to mock directives in unit tests. To see this, check out the answer by Sylvain to this StackOverflow question: [How do you mock directives to enable unit testing of higher level directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533052/how-do-you-mock-directives-to-enable-unit-testing-of-higher-level-directive).